# Como se comporta um método assíncrono executando um método síncrono em Python?

Tags: python-3.x, funções

Em Python um método assíncrono é capaz de executar em paralelo, mas se dentro dele eu tiver uma função "normal", ela também será executada de forma assíncrona ou a partir daquele momento a execução será "travada" e outras funções não poderão ser executadas "ao mesmo tempo"?

```
def funcao_normal():
    # algum código aki...

async def funcao_assincrona():
    # algum código aki...
    funcao_normal()
    
await funcao_assincrona()
```

Comment: Tem conhecimento sobre o conceito de corotinas?

Comment: Não, na vdd acabei de chegar nesse negócio de assíncrono, mas agora sei o nome que eu tenho que procurar (corotinas né?) Obg @Woss

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando você chama um código síncrono de uma função assíncrona o *event loop* ficará travado até a função síncrona retornar. Ou seja, caso seja uma chamada não bloqueante (e.g. uma função que apenas formata strings) não haverá tanto problema. No entanto, se for uma chamada bloqueante como acesso a banco de dados, o *event loop* pode ficar travado por mais tempo do que o esperado não dando chance a outras corotinas rodarem.

O ideal é não fazer chamadas síncronas bloqueantes a partir de código assíncrono, mas caso seja necessário, a forma correta é criar um executar e colocar a função síncrona para rodar dentro dele:

```
async def async_func():
    executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    result = await loop.run_in_executor(executor, sync_function, *args_for_sync_func)
```

Dessa forma, a função síncrona rodará no *event loop* atual.